# In Pharo/Smalltalk: How to read a file with a specific encoding?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am currently reading a file like this:

```
dir := FileSystem disk workingDirectory.
stream := (dir / 'test.txt' ) readStream.
line := stream nextLine.
```

This works when the file is `utf-8` encoded but I could not find out what to do when the file has another encoding.

Comment: Hint: Look for implementors (and senders) of `#encoding:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Pharo 7 there's this [guide for file streams](https://github.com/pavel-krivanek/pharoMaterials/blob/master/Filestreams.MD), which proposes:

```
('test.txt' asFileReference)
    readStreamEncoded: 'cp-1250' do: [ :stream |
        stream upToEnd ].
```

Answer (score 5):

The classes `ZnCharacterReadStream` and `ZnCharacterWriteStream` provide
functionality to work with encoded character streams other then `UTF-8` (which is the default). First, the file stream needs to be converted into a `binary` stream. After this, it can be wrapped by a `ZnCharacter*Stream`. Here is a full example for writing and reading a file:

```
dir := FileSystem disk workingDirectory.

(dir / 'test.txt') writeStreamDo: [ :out |
  encoded := ZnCharacterWriteStream on: (out binary) encoding: 'cp1252'.
  encoded nextPutAll: 'Über?'.
].

content := '?'.
(dir / 'test.txt') readStreamDo: [ :in |
  decoded := ZnCharacterReadStream on: (in binary) encoding: 'cp1252'.
  content := decoded nextLine.
].
content. " -> should evaluate to 'Über?'"
```

For more details, the book [Enterprise Pharo a Web Perspective](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283521517_Enterprise_Pharo_a_Web_Perspective) has a chapter about character encoding.